# Connecting two TShape objects

Tags: drag-and-drop, lazarus

i'm trying to do simple game in lazarus, but i'm stuck with one thing that i don't really want to overcomplicate. I have some circles on the screen (pretty small ones, 10pixels diameter) and i want to draw lines between two selected. So i thought i gonna make invisible hitboxes. I took care that two hitboxes doesn't intersect.

And i want to do simple drag and drop. If i drag circle or it's hitbox and drop it on another circle or it's hitbox i want to draw a line between those two circles. And my question is: is there a elegant way of knowing which circle belongs to a hitbox? Or maybe some other nice solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

*I'm not sure how exactly you have your setup, so the answer is quite generic.*

You can start with the following:

1. Have a function to detect which circle is below cursor - `CircleHitTest(X,Y: Integer): Integer;`. If there's no circle at given XY - return -1.
2. Upon `MouseDown` detect which circle was under a cursor and store it's Id in variable `DrawFrom`.
3. Upon `MouseUp` detect which circle was under a cursor and store it's Id in variable `DrawTo`
4. If `DrawFrom` and `DrawTo` are two different and valid circles - draw a line between them.